# Flutter how to validate any ssn using RegExp

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to validate my ssn using
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp()),

I want it to start with 1 or 2  with 10 length and last 9th numbers any number
,only first one should be 1 or 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 TextFormField(
            inputFormatters: [
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[12][0-9]*$')),
            ],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              labelText: 'PAN Number',
            ),
          )
```